# Does JQuery AJAX have a different User Session than a postback to the same website?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

Does JQuery AJAX have a different User Session than a postback to the same website?

I am trying to send data to a MVC2 Controller through a Jquery Ajax POST with a querystring on it and then this MVC2 Controller will take the data from querystring and place it into the User's Session.  Successfully while debugging I see that the Controller grabs the querystring, sets a session variable and in the immediate windows I can pull up the Session contents again.

Later my users will come along use a different Controller but same domain and I will check for that User's Session information.  It appears to be a whole new User Session even though it is the same user and the same domain.

Any ideas why this might be happening would help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Ajax posting will be using the same session so you might have a problem in your code?  Can you post some of it that is relevant.